# Idiom for needing to focus on something

Tags: idioms

Is there an idiom or a phrase people use at work one needs to fully focus on a specific task? Thought I've heard it at work before, but can't think of it right this second..

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example scenario, sentence, or dialogue. You can [edit] your post to include more details.

Comment: "stay focused" or "Keep your eye on the ball"? " And is this said by the person trying to focus, or the potential distracters?

Answer (score 1):

Put my nose to the grindstone.

Knuckle down.

Put my head down.

Get stuck in.

Get in the zone.

Throw myself into the task.

Really go at it.

Put everything into the task.

Etc

Comment: "Head Down" is a very trendy choice.  It seems to be the one I hear most these days.

Answer (score 0):

Possible phrases are

> I'm focused right now.
>   I'm in the zone.
>   I have to concentrate.

but usually what you will get from someone who is concentrating is

> Stop bothering me!
>   Go away!